# Spring data rest response too much slow

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-rest

in a spring data rest API with hibernate, PostgreSQL, i face a problem of slow response that takes ~ 17s every time i call: the endpoint: http://server:8080/api/books/

```
public class Book implements Serializable {
   // .....
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private String reference;

    private LocalDate edited;

    private Integer quantity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("started DESC")
    private Set<Student> readers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("started DESC")
    private Set<Professor> updaters;

   // .....
}



public class Student implements Serializable {
  // .....
  // .....
}

public class Professor implements Serializable {
  // .....
  // .....
}


@RepositoryRestResource(path = "books", collectionResourceRel = "books")
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, UUID> {
}
```

my database has over then 5000 of book records
how can i' speedup this request

Comment: If the order is important in your collections you should not use `Set` (readers, updaters). You should use `List`

Comment: the order is not so important, Set doesn’t allow duplicate elements

Comment: It's difficult to make some conclusion about your performance problem from this hibernate mapping. I would suggest you to enable hibernate sql traces (`show_sql`, `format_sql`, `use_sql_comments`) and analize generated sql queries when you send your request. Maybe it's N+1 problem ...

Comment: And if `the order is not so important` why do you use `@OrderBy("started DESC")` ?

Comment: List preserve the order in which records are saved it's some thing quite different from student/professor started reading/reviewing a book.

Comment: *If the order is important in your collections you should not use Set*. -- Hibernate will order the set using something like `LinkedHashSet` so it is perfectly acceptable to map ordered collections as Sets.